# Cannot see parent variable after changing to use custom dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component with 2 direct children, both of which use the `event` variable that is held within the parent. However, upon changing one of the components which uses a dropdown list from using a `<select>` to a custom-animated dropdown... I can no longer see the `event` within this child, despite using the near-identical code.

**Parent.ts**

```
event: IEvent;

constructor(private eventService: EventService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.subToEventService();
}

subToEventService() {
  this.eventService.eventSubject
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.event = res;
  }
}
```

**Child 1 (can see event)**

```
export class ChildOne extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(eventService: EventService) {
    super(eventService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.event);
  }

}
```

**Child 2 (cannot see event)**

```
export class ChildTwo extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: ElementRef;

  expanded = false;

  constructor(eventService: EventService) {
    super(eventService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.event);
  }

  toggleDropdown() {
    const dropdown = this.dropdown.nativeElement;

    if (this.expanded) {
      TweenMax.to(dropdown, 0.5, {...});
    } else {
      TweenMax.to(dropdown, 0.5, {...});
    }
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }

  determineStyle() {
    const style = this.dropdown.nativeElement.style;
    style.height = this.expanded ? 376 : 34;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your child components, you are overriding the `ngOnInit` method of the `ParentComponent` class.

You need to call `super.ngOnInit();` on both child `ngOnInit` to subscribe to your subject inside those components.

Comment: Where would I use `super.ngOnInit( )`?]

Comment: inside the methods ngOnInit of the Children `ngOnInit(){ super.ngOnInit(); }`

Comment: Ah! Yes this works now! I had gotten around it initially by using ngAfterViewInit, but I like to use OnInit preferably :-)

Comment: Glad I could help 